# How can I solve this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation and when I try to solve it by using the "NDSolve" command, the Mathematica gives an error. The differential equation and error are as follows

```
NDSolve[{Y''[a] + 51/20 Y'[a]/a - 9/20 a^-3 Y[a] == 0, Y[1] == 1, 
Y'[1/1000] == 1}, Y, {a, 1/1000, 1}]

NDSolve: At a == 0.001`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or 
stiff system suspected.
```

I will be thankful if someone help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the mentioned warning in _v11.3_ and _v12_. Which version are you in?

Answer (score 2):

```
DSolve[{y''[a] + 51/20 y'[a]/a - 9/20 a^-3 y[a] == 0, y[1] == 1, 
  y'[1/1000] == 1}, y, {a, 1/1000, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
NDSolve[{Y''[a] + 51/20 Y'[a]/a - 9/20 a^-3 Y[a] == 0, Y[1] == 1, 
Y'[1/1000] == 1}, Y, {a, 1, 1/1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 24]
Plot[Evaluate[Y[a] /. %], {a, 1, 1/1000}]
```

[image]